# I need to redirect product add to cart button to checkout page instead of cart page

Tags: checkout, magento-1, onepage-checkout

I have **BuyNow** button on my product page when I clicked on button it should redirect to checkout page and product should be added to cart page, please tell me proper solution over this how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658322/magento-add-to-cart-and-redirect-to-checkout-product-page-on-checkout-button

Answer (score 4):

Swash_nam, Goto cartcontroller (`app>code>core>Mage>Checkout>controllers>CartController.php`)'s function goback

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
```

Go to `Admin>Configuration>Sales>Checkout>Shopping Cart>After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` and make it `yes`

Comment: Unless I am missing something in the question as @Amit shows above this is just a setting.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone suggest that you should make changes to core code, ignore it! Making changes to core files is a Bad Thing and every Magento developer worth its salt avoids it at all costs.

That being said there's number of ways to achieve it. I would use observers. There's an excellent tutorial from Inchoo about building an observer extension which deal with something similar. I'm not :

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/tracking-magento-add-product-to-cart-action-for-analytic-software-purpose/

However, instead of `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add`, I would `add_to_cart_after` event.

Check also this article for the additional information:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/dispatching-before-and-after-events-to-magento-core-actions/

To redirect Magento to checkout use something similar in the Observer code:

```
$response = $observer->getResponse();
$url = Mage::helper('checkout/url')->getCheckoutUrl();
$response->setRedirect($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer form this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4053248/3018289

Here is a copy for quick access.

You could create an observer listening for the checkout_cart_add_product_complete event and in there you could do something like the following

```
  public function addToCartComplete(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    // Send the user to the Item added page
    $response = $observer->getResponse();
    $request = $observer->getRequest();
    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
}
```

Your config would look something like this

```
 <frontend>
    <events>
    <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
      <observers>
        <packagename_modulename_observer>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>
          <method>addToCartComplete</method>
        </packagename_modulename_observer>
      </observers>
      </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
   </events>
   </frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good tutorial to tell about how to create a module to make redirect cart to checkout more simple: 
https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-redirect-to-checkout-after-adding-to-cart-an-easy-how-to-guide/

I see that it give a detaied instruction aboutcreating a module by using envent Observer method the use config co control redirect cart to checkout